# Inner product of matrix relative to a base

Tags: matrices, inner-products

find the matrix $A$ that represents the usual inner product on $R^2$ relative  to the given base of $R^2$ $S=\{(1,3),(2,5)\}$. How do I proceed if the same question would be for an inner product on $R^3$ and again, a suitable basis. What is the logic? and how is this matrix related to the positive definite matrix?

Comment: The matrix $A$ is the matrix associated to the inner product which is a symmetric bilinear form, so you have to find the images of your vector that represent $a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22}$

Answer (score 0):

compute $a_{11}=<v_1,v_1>$,
$a_{12}=<v_1,v_2>=<v_2,v_1>=a_{21}$
$,a_{22}=<v_2,v_2>$.Then your desired matrix will be 
$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}& a_{12}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$